# simplify summation computation (sigma sign) in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I need to count the percentage of each group(from A to G) and use six different columns to divide by the same one(like G representing the total). And then I need to count calculate something called [HHI](http://www.domysciencehomework.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/08/herfindahl-hirschman-index.png). My equation has a "1-" in front of the sigma sign. Thus, I need to square those columns and then add them up and then use 1 minus the addition. I need to keep those columns of percentage in my dataframe. Please help me to simplify the following code:

```
  df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(20, 7), columns=list("ABCDEFG"))

  #percentage
        df["pct_A"] = df_race.A / df_race.G
        df["pct_B"] = df_race.B / df_race.G
        df["pct_C"] = df_race.C / df_race.G
        df["pct_D"] = df_race.D / df_race.G
        df["pct_E"] = df_race.E / df_race.G
        df["pct_F"] = df_race.F / df_race.G

    #HHI Index
        df["hhi"] = 1-(df.pct_A**2 + df.pct_B**2 + df.pct_C**2 + 
                       df.pct_D**2 + df.pct_E**2 + df.pct_F**2)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess this would help. 
I am creating a df with random values with 7 columns, dividing the first 6 with 7th column and then calculating **hhi** using a helper function **calculate_hhi**.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(20, 7), columns=list('ABCDEFG'))

def calculate_hhi(row):
    hhi = 1 - (row['A']**2 + row['B']**2 + row['C']**2 + row['D']**2 + row['E']**2 + row['F']**2 )
    return hhi 

df.iloc[:, 0:6] = df.iloc[:, 0:6].apply(lambda x: x/df.G, axis=0)
df['hhi'] = df.apply(calculate_hhi, axis=1)
```

Comment: Thank you!  It works but the columns' name stays the same. Is there anything I can add to the lambda part to change the name "race_" to "pct_"

Comment: I add df_race.columns = df_race.columns.str.replace("race", "pct")

Comment: Get your column names by `df.columns` and then
`df.columns = ['pct_white', 'pct_black']` give all the column names and alter the names you want to be renamed in the new column name assignment.

Comment: In the example you created, if I use `df.iloc[:, 0:7].apply(lambda x : x**2, axis=1)`. That will square each column. what else can I put inside of lambda to let it return the sum of first 7 columns (axis = 1) after squaring them, and assign those values to be my 8th column?

Comment: You can do this to add the columns and store it to another column.
`col_list = ['A', 'B', 'C']`  then 
`df['E'] = df[col_list].sum(axis=1)` or you can just write 
`df.iloc[:, 0:7].apply(lambda x : x**2, axis=1).sum(axis=1)` but then store it to some column

Answer (score 1):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(20, 7), columns=list("ABCDEFG"))
```

What I evetually used is (my dataset contains missing values):

```
df.iloc[:, 0:6] = df.iloc[:, 0:6].apply(lambda x: x/df.G)
df["hhi"] = 1 - df.iloc[:, 0:6].apply(lambda x: x**2).sum(skipna=False, axis=1)
```